# Homebrew: Why is java not installed as a dependency for Tomcat?

Tags: homebrew, java

`Java` is listed in [Tomcat's dependency list](http://brewformulas.org/Tomcat). But when I install `tomcat` there is no `java`. Why?

```
$brew install tomcat
$brew list | grep java | wc -l
0
```

Comment: Probably Java (Oracle/Apple) is already installed: check `brew config | grep Java`!

Comment: @klanomath you are right. I'll accept the answer if you transform your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Java was already installed previously (either the Oracle or the outdated Apple Java installer) Tomcat's requirements are met and brew won't install another Java.

The small green checkmark (or red cross if Java has to be installed) will indicate this:

[image]